# iOS 14 crash UITextField with textColor = [ UIColor colorWithCIColor: ]

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, runtime, uicolor

Crash:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [ super viewDidLoad ];
    
    UITextField * textField = [ [ UITextField alloc ] init ];
    textField.textColor = [ UIColor colorWithCIColor:[ CIColor colorWithString:@"0 0 0 1" ] ];
    [ self.view addSubview:textField ];
}
```

Xcode console:

> warning: could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data
> in the process. This may reduce the quality of type information
> available.

Don't crash:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [ super viewDidLoad ];
    
    UITextField * textField = [ [ UITextField alloc ] init ];
    textField.text = @"text";
    textField.textColor = [ UIColor colorWithCIColor:[ CIColor colorWithString:@"0 0 0 1" ] ];
    [ self.view addSubview:textField ];
}
```

in empty project and empty UIViewController. iOS 14.2 / iPhone XS / Xcode 12.2 (12B45b).

Also it crash after clear all existing text in UItextFiled.

Comment: Looks like really funny quirky bug. I think it is some kind of initialisation problem. If you do e.g. ```UIColor.blackColor``` then it is fine. Other way to solve it is to set the text to anything and it works, but setting it to e.g. ```@""``` empty string and it crashes again. (PS - love your wide format syntax)

Comment: And what's the crash log/real error? Because that's a warning, not a crash error. Stacktrace maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I verified this crash in a test app. Turns out, it's an infinitely-self-recursing, stack-delving kind of crash (see stack trace).

It's crashing because of the way you're initializing your UIColor from a CIColor. This is highly unconventional. CIColor objects really are meant to be used in the context of CoreImage.

If you do `textField.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];` there is no crash.

All this being said, your code probably *shouldn't* be crashing, and it's likely a bug in the API. It might be worth filing a bug report.

[image]